# 404 not redirecting a unknown php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using LAMP Apache with CentOs 6.9

My site is `abcd.xyz.com`
that type sub-domain also it hosted on a Virtual host.

When I wrote 
`abcd.xyz.com/hshgdgd`  or `abcd.xyz.com/hshgdgd.ht`, it redirecting 404 page fine but when I wrote extension .php like `abcd.xyz.com/hshgdgd.php`,
it's not redirecting just telling `File not found`.

My .htaccess below:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 xyz.com
ErrorDocument 402 xyz.com
ErrorDocument 403 xyz.com
ErrorDocument 500 xyz.com
```

mod rewrite it on/allow my domain root folder in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Are those ErrorDocument lines referencing real files on the file system? (They shouldn't be domains - and normally, they have path information, such as "/error_page.php")